# Azure Search queries including too many results due to extra wildcard in fullpath_1 query with space

Tags: azure, azure-search

We are using Azure Search to find items by path. We apply the following search code:

```
var filterPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
filterPredicate.And(x => x.Path.StartsWith(rootItem.Paths.Path));
var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Filter(filterPredicate);
​SearchResults<SearchResultItem> results = query.GetResults();
```

However, when we do this with a path that includes spaces, the query gets generated as the below query (taken from the logs):

```
10216 15:53:13 INFO  AzureSearch Query [sitecore_master_index]: &search=(fullpath_1:(/\/sitecore\/content\/Sites\/Site.*/ /1\/Services\/ServiceA.*/))&queryType=full&$skip=0&$top=3&$count=true
```

Notice the extra `.*` included after the `Site` of `Site 1`. This means that when the query gets executed, it returns all results whose path starts with `/sitecore/content/Sites/Site` instead of only the results below the complete path.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

> Environment:
>
> - Sitecore 9.0.2
> - Azure PaaS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use the string based full path, use the `IEnumerable<ID> Paths` property:

```
var filterPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<SearchResultItem>();
filterPredicate.And(x => x.Paths.Contains(rootItem.ID));
var query = context.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>().Filter(filterPredicate);
​SearchResults<SearchResultItem> results = query.GetResults();
```

That should give you more accurate results than searching a string that is tokenized.

Comment: While this does not fix the incorrect query generation, it does fix my issue. Thanks, Richard!